# What does ただ mean in this context, following a verb and before ひとり?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

> 怒られるタイプの男子に囲まれている**ただ**ひとりの怒られるタイプの女子。
>   I'm surrounded by boys who are the "getting scolded" type (but?) I'm the only girl *of that sort*.

Does ただ mean 'but' in this context? If so, when/how should I use it. How, for example, does it differ from けど?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `ただ` appears directly before a numeral + quantifier pair, like in the phrases `ただひとり` or `ただひとつ`, it usually has this meaning:

> 数量・程度などがきわめて少ないさま。たった。わずかに。「ただ一人だけ生き残る」
>
> (二-③ in 明鏡国語辞典)

I think it corresponds to the word 'only' in your translation, as part of `ただひとり`.  I don't think it means 'but' here.  There isn't any conjunction in the original Japanese noun phrase – `怒られるタイプの男子に囲まれている` is a relative clause modifying `（ただひとりの怒られるタイプの）女子`.

Comment: I used 'only' to translate ひとりの. So ただ emphasises the 'singleness'? I hadn't appreciated that the first phrase was modifying 女子. It looked too far away. Thanks.

Comment: It's kind of like 'just one (person)' or 'only one (person)' as opposed to 'one (person)'.